# convert pandas Series of lists of strings to float - type issues

Tags: python, arrays, pandas

How do I properly convert this pandas series/array which for some reason it sees as an object into a float ? each element in each line of the array needs to be converted.

I've tried to_numeric but I get dataType errors

```
<PandasArray>
[['1703.0', '1144.0', '2172.0', '735.0'],
 ['1120.0', '637.0', '2026.0', '1599.0'],
 ['2663.0', '859.0', '2281.0', '1487.0'],
           ['1407.0', '1987.0', '696.0'],
           ['1392.0', '1971.0', '552.0'],
           ['1025.0', '1566.0', '581.0'],
                              ['768.24'],
                               ['527.0'],
                              ['731.96'],
                              ['664.48']]
Length: 10, dtype: object
```

even if I use {col: dtype, …} from the spec I get a slightly different error of
`TypeError: unhashable type: 'Series'`

with  `df['mycol'].astype({mycol: float}, errors='raise', copy=True)`

Comment: The values look like strings. What about .astype(float)

Comment: with that I get ```ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.``` and ```TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'```

Comment: IIRC, `PandasArray` is to be deprecated (or already is). You should consider move away from that. That said, each of the cell is a list, you need to apply the float type to the elements of the list, not the list itself.

Comment: `df['mycol'].apply(lambda x: list(map(float, x)))` would work.

Comment: @QuangHoang can you explain how the above works? I haven't been able to get any success with it yet

Answer (score 0):

While you *can* initialize a Series or DataFrame as object type, with values equal to lists or other containers pointing to other data, Pandas is not designed to hold data structures like this. If you organize your data this way, you will get many of the nice features of pandas such as indexing and broadcasting, but it will not be fast, and it may behave in ways you're not expecting. As mentioned in the comments, you *can* convert the elements inside each list to a float, but the result will not be an optimized numpy jagged array of e.g. np.float64. Instead, you have a `Series` of object type, containing python lists which can hold pure-python `str` or `float` data. The performance will in most cases be worse than pure-python containers such as dictionaries.

This could be a job for the scikit extension library [awkward arrays](https://github.com/scikit-hep/awkward#readme). It's young but under active development and the goal is very high performance and interoperability for working with large jagged/irregular datasets for applications such as particle physics.

```py
In [1]: import awkward as ak, numpy as np

In [2]: arr = ak.Array(
   ...:  [['1703.0', '1144.0', '2172.0', '735.0'],
   ...:   ['1120.0', '637.0', '2026.0', '1599.0'],
   ...:   ['2663.0', '859.0', '2281.0', '1487.0'],
   ...:             ['1407.0', '1987.0', '696.0'],
   ...:             ['1392.0', '1971.0', '552.0'],
   ...:             ['1025.0', '1566.0', '581.0'],
   ...:                                ['768.24'],
   ...:                                 ['527.0'],
   ...:                                ['731.96'],
   ...:                                ['664.48'],
   ...: ])
```

You can convert this to float using the [`ak.strings_astype`](https://awkward-array.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_auto/ak.strings_astype.html) function:

```py
In [17]: arrf = ak.strings_astype(arr, np.float32)

In [18]: arrf
Out[18]: <Array [[1.7e+03, 1.14e+03, ... [664]] type='10 * var * float32'>
```

You can also do all kinds of math and slicing operations in a way that works natively with the structure of the data. For example, let's say we wanted to pull out the last element along the second dimension. In `awkward`, this is a natural slicing operation:

```py
In [20]: arrf[..., -1:]
Out[20]: <Array [[735], [1.6e+03], ... [732], [664]] type='10 * var * float32'>
```

See the [user guide](https://awkward-array.org/what-is-awkward.html) and the [API documentation](https://awkward-array.readthedocs.io/en/latest) for more info.

Comment: trying this approach I get a fair number odd values 
```[[1.7e+03, 1.14e+03, 2.17e+03, 735], [1.12e+03, 637, ... [527], [732], [664]]```

Comment: also seeing ```cannot slice NumpyArray by field name

(https://github.com/scikit-hep/awkward-1.0/blob/1.8.0/src/libawkward/array/NumpyArray.cpp#L1292)```

Comment: Awkward does round the values pretty heavily in the display, but the full values should still be there. And to slice by field make you need to name your fields so you can’t just throw an unlabeled array at it like in my example. I’ve never used awkward and when playing around with it for this example it definitely seems like there is a learning curve. So I’m not saying it will be easy. But the performance should be much better than if you’re using pandas as an interface to python lists.